# Populate Spinner

Tags: java, android, android-spinner, android-checkbox

I have 4 checkboxes, when I check tick one, two or more. I want to populate my spinner with values, 1-5 if checkbox 1 is checked, 6-10 if checkbox 2 is checked, etc.. I have this logic here.

```
public void populateSpinnerToothNumber() {
    if (cbQuadrant1.isChecked()) {
        ArrayList<String> toothNumber = new ArrayList<>();
        toothNumber.add("1");
        toothNumber.add("2");
        toothNumber.add("3");
        toothNumber.add("4");
        toothNumber.add("5");

        ArrayAdapter<String> stringArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item, toothNumber);
        spinnerToothNumber.setAdapter(stringArrayAdapter);
    } else if (cbQuadrant2.isChecked()) {

    } else if (cbQuadrant3.isChecked()) {

    } else if (cbQuadrant4.isChecked()) {

    } else if (cbQuadrant1.isChecked() && cbQuadrant2.isChecked()) {
        ArrayList<String> toothNumber = new ArrayList<>();
        toothNumber.add("1");
        toothNumber.add("2");
        toothNumber.add("3");
        toothNumber.add("4");
        toothNumber.add("5");
        toothNumber.add("6");
        toothNumber.add("7");
        toothNumber.add("8");
        toothNumber.add("9");
        toothNumber.add("10");

        ArrayAdapter<String> stringArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item, toothNumber);
        spinnerToothNumber.setAdapter(stringArrayAdapter);
    }
}
```

How can I improve the logic?

**UPDATE**

```
public void populateSpinnerToothNumber() {
    final ArrayList<String> toothNumber = new ArrayList<>();

    cbQuadrant1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
            for (int x = 1; x <= 5; x++) {
                toothNumber.add(String.valueOf(x));
            }
        }
    });

    cbQuadrant2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
            for (int x = 6; x <= 10; x++) {
                toothNumber.add(String.valueOf(x));
            }
        }
    });

    cbQuadrant3.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
            for (int x = 11; x <= 15; x++) {
                toothNumber.add(String.valueOf(x));
            }
        }
    });

    cbQuadrant4.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
            for (int x = 16; x <= 20; x++) {
                toothNumber.add(String.valueOf(x));
            }
        }
    });

    ArrayAdapter<String> stringArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item, toothNumber);
    spinnerToothNumber.setAdapter(stringArrayAdapter);
}
```

This solved the problem :) Managed it with checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener Thanks for helping! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use **[OnCheckedChangeListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener.html)**

> Interface definition for a callback to be invoked when the checked state of a compound button changed.

**sample code**

```
 checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

      @Override
      public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
           if (isChecked) {
               ArrayList<String> toothNumber = new ArrayList<>();
               toothNumber.add("1");
               toothNumber.add("2");
               toothNumber.add("3");
               toothNumber.add("4");
               toothNumber.add("5");
               ArrayAdapter<String> stringArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item, toothNumber);
               spinnerToothNumber.setAdapter(stringArrayAdapter);
            }
          }
        }
    );

    checkBox2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

          @Override
          public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
           if (isChecked) {
                ArrayList<String> toothNumber = new ArrayList<>();
                toothNumber.add("1");
                toothNumber.add("2");
                toothNumber.add("3");
                toothNumber.add("4");
                toothNumber.add("5");
                toothNumber.add("6");
                toothNumber.add("7");
                toothNumber.add("8");
                toothNumber.add("9");
                toothNumber.add("10");
                ArrayAdapter<String> stringArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item, toothNumber);
                  spinnerToothNumber.setAdapter(stringArrayAdapter);
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
    );
```

Comment: What if check box 1 and 2 is checked? Or what if check box 1 and 3 is checked?

Comment: you have to mange all check box changed listener for that my above ans is just snippet code to guide you now you can mange all check box changed listener as per your requirement @KyleAnthonyDizon

Comment: Oh, okay okay. I'll try and improve the logic right now. Thanks mate!

Comment: most welcome @KyleAnthonyDizon happy to help you let me know if any query

Answer (score 2):

Adding to @Nilesh Rathod. You can have a method like called `populateSpinner (int bgCount, int Endcount)` which takes in the amount of tooth number needed from the beginning range to the end.

```
private void populateSpinner (int bgCount, int Endcount) {
    ArrayList<String> toothNumber = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = bgCount; i < Endcount; i++) {
          toothNumber.add(i);
     }
    ArrayAdapter<String> stringArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item, toothNumber);
    spinnerToothNumber.setAdapter(stringArrayAdapter);
}
```

Call the method like this in your check boxes **OnCheckedChangeListener**.
`populateSpinner (1, 5);`